# Create secret "kubernetes.io/service-account-token" with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create secret for my service account with kubectl, but cannot do this. Is it possible?

```
➤ kubectl create secret generic test --type=kubernetes.io/service-account-token -n dev
error: failed to create secret Secret "test" is invalid: metadata.annotations[kubernetes.io/service-account.name]: Required value
```

I understand the error, but I can't find an example anywhere on how to create these types of secrets from the command line. From a file, I create a secret of this type without any problems.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can of course do something like `kubectl create secret generic test --type=kubernetes.io/service-account-token -o json --dry-run=client  | jq '.metadata.annotations = {"kubernetes.io/service-account.name": "default"}' | kubectl apply -f-`, but that's not particularly convenient. As a matter of practice, I very rarely end up creating resources "on the fly" like that: I generate all resources from files store in a git repository using `kustomize` (or the equivalent `kubectl apply -k` command).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm using resource files too, but I wanted to try to remake some things with commands. Looks more compact.

Comment: My experience has been that a set of YAML files you can `kubectl apply` (or `helm install`) is generally more maintainable than a set of imperative `kubectl create` commands.

Comment: I have been working with kubernetes for many years, I understand that you have to enter, but at the moment I wanted to write this for the script with a command. I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check my example (working):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: prod-vault-auth-secret
  namespace: prod-vault
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: prod-vault-auth
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```